# How can I add to mongoose nested document, not overwrite it?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

**This is my mongoose model:**

```
...
images: new Schema({
 poster: new Schema({
   small: String,
   medium: String,
   big: String
 }, { _id: false }),
 backdrop: new Schema({
   small: String,
   medium: String,
   big: String
 }, { _id: false })
}, { _id: false }),
...
```

**This is what I'm doing:**
I'm getting poster, and update `images` like this:

```
Movie.findOneAndUpdate({
id: {
    imdb: movie.id.imdb
}
}, {
    images: {
        backdrop: {
            small: backdrops.small,
            medium: backdrops.medium,
            big: backdrops.big
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine. then I get Backdrops and I update `images` like this:

```
Movie.findOneAndUpdate({
    id: {
        imdb: movie.id.imdb
    }
}, {
    images: {
        backdrop: {
            small: backdrops.small,
            medium: backdrops.medium,
            big: backdrops.big
        }
    }
}
```

**problem is**
It overwrites the whole `images` document, not adding `backdrops` along `poster`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got it**
instead this:

```
images: {
    backdrop: {
        small: backdrops.small,
        medium: backdrops.medium,
        big: backdrops.big
    }
}
```

I should use

```
'images.backdrop': {
    small: backdrops.small,
    medium: backdrops.medium,
    big: backdrops.big
}
```